# Prevent XML External Entity Injections in Geotools WMS Client

Tags: geotools

I'm using Geotools 11.5 and would like to protect against [XML External Entity Injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) when using the Geotools WMS client (gt-wms). The linked OWASP page suggests disallowing doctypes as a means of achieving this with a SAXParserFactory, which I believe is used by gt-wms. Is there any way of disallowing doctypes when using gt-wms?

Possibly related is that even in the later versions of [org.geotools.xml.DocumentFactory:152-153](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/42c4cc0c3d850b1dea50c07108f171aace35a798/modules/library/xml/src/main/java/org/geotools/xml/DocumentFactory.java#L152) appear to have the lines of code needed to fix the issue, but they are commented out? The github history doesn't go back that far, can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: You will probably do better asking on the geotools users list for questions like this, but at first glance (http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/xml/internal/index.html) gt-wms uses the GTXML framework.

Comment: Also 11.5 is no longer a supported version, so please upgrade to 14.5 or 15.1

Comment: Hi iant, I've now updated to 15.1. This didn't fix the issue but of course did improve the overall quality of the project. I'll send a mail out on the mailing list and post what I find here. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out this was a bug in Geotools now fixed in 15.2. See here for information on how to configure XML parsing such that local filesystem DTDs can be disabled: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/metadata/geotools.html#xml